Access TanStack Query Cache in VueJs
I have 2 routes in my vue js application. 

/dashboard
/dashboard/about-me

Dashboard page is the wrapper of about-me page which is rendered using <RouterView />  within Dashboard.
 
Inside dashboard i have a get request that uses `useQuery`, it work perfectly. 
 In AboutMe page i need the response data from that query from Dashboard. To access data i use
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
const userQuery = queryClient.getQueryData(['user', '1aa20fd9-81d2-4248-a09e-17822731ddb9']);
console.log(userQuery);

When i navigate to dashboard/about-me i see data there as is expected.

Issue: If i refresh the /dashboard/me page i get undefined in console.log, because onSuccess from the dashboard query is triggered after the AboutMe page is mounted and this cause the issue. 
Question: Is there a way to access cache data in AboutMe page when i refresh the page?

Consider explaining your case further. It's unknown how useQuery is used. If the routes rely on query results, I'd expect you have to block navigation with suspense or router hooks and use a promise from prefetchQuery or fetchQuery
